# How to install PHRETS 2.0?

Tags: php, phrets

What are all the step by step process to install phrets in ubuntu?

I tried the following, but then unable to run phrets

- First I got installed composer.
- Then I ran `composer require troydavisson/phrets`
- Now I have two files composer.json and composer.lock, and a folder named "vendor"
- Inside vendor folder, I can see autoload.php file and some other folders

Now I tried the sample code from [phrets git](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS)

But then am getting the following error,

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in /var/www/testing/newphrets.php on line 7

Please advice what am missing here. Am planning to switch my project from old version to phrets 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: Why does this have to be so confusing, why can't we just download the files and then upload them to the server. Instead we have to go through this composer nightmare which takes hours to figure out. There is no clear documentation how to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Troy's [PHRETS 2.0 Logging video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MPJwsLtG70) and [looking at PHRETS' `composer.json`](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/blob/master/composer.json), you can see that you need to do one of two things. Either,

(a) Add `monolog` to your project's `composer.json`,

```
{
    "require": {
        "troydavisson/phrets": "2.*",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.10"
    }
}
```

and run `composer update` in your project's root directory.

or,

(b) Since `monolog` is in PHRETS' `composer.json` file but in the `require-dev` section, run `composer install --dev` or `composer update --dev` [to indicate you're currently in development](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) and would like to use the development libraries.

Comment: remove the trailing comma after the monolog line, it will cause an error

Comment: Can someone show how to do this step by step? For example Im using dreamhost. What do I do? I don't even know where to start. Everyone says google "get started with composer" but that is all confusing. I need a 5th grader example please! Not a well rounded pro answer.